# Alternative to pseudo element in iframe

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, linear-gradients

I'm part of a website where I can design and sell products. They let me fancy up each product's webpage, and because I have multiple products, I want to just use one external stylesheet to rule them all (and in the darkness, bind them).

The problem is, for the site's safety, the area I can code in is an iframe. (I get and support why they do that.) I made a template of my code using raw HTML so I could code it offline until I liked it, then upload it directly and BAM, every product page with the underlying HTML would look correctly matching.

My code uses pseudo elements to position a gradient box on top of a bordered div. It looks *great* (to me) as working HTML but the pseudo element gradient refuses to load when placed inside the iframe. I tried *not* using the pseudo element style and made stacked divs using z-index, but I did it quite wrong and it came out a mess.

Here's my HTML version. How can I get the gradient to stack and be sized correctly over top the fancy-bordered divs? I don't care *what code* will accomplish this. I just need to accomplish this.

```css
body {
 background: url('BlackLeather.jpg') repeat; background-color: #000000;
 color: #9200b0;
}
#container {
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 position: relative;
}
#footer {
  text-align:center;
}
.border {
 border: 10px solid;
 position: relative;
 border-image: url('TigerPurpleSeamless225.jpg') 30 round;
 margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
}

.shine::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: -9; left: -9; bottom: -9; right: -9;
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
  
 box-shadow:
  0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset,
  0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
  0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
  
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;

 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(96,103,104,0.3) 0%,rgba(187,187,187,0.3) 3%,rgba(187,187,187,0.3) 27%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 28%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 73%,rgba(75,80,81,0.3) 88%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 97%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

```html
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.cafenocturne.com/IMVU/products/Shop_Code/ShopCSS.css">
</HEAD>

<div id="container">
  <div id="header" class="border shine">
   <br><img src='' alt=''>
   [Header Image]<br><br>
   BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH
  </div>

 <div id="description" class="border shine">
  <br>Description of product.<br><br>
   BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH
 </div>

 <div id="productimages" class="border shine">
  <br><img src='' alt='Product Preview'>
   BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH
 </div>

 <div id="shine">
  <div id="footer" class="border shine">
  <!-- <a href="https://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?manufacturers_id=5315966" target="_blank">
  <img src="" border="0"></a> --> [Footer Banner]<br>
 </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Now the gradient isn't showing up in my code snippets on Stack, likely for the same reason, so here's a working copy on my own server so you can see what I'm attempting to achieve: [Shop Layout Code](http://www.cafenocturne.com/IMVU/products/Shop_Code/ShopLayoutCode.html)

Comment: Link not working

Comment: Thank you! Fixed!